# How to deploy my xampp locahost api project to an online webhosting server

Tags: php, mysql, api, xampp, web-hosting

I have an API project that i created which is working perfectly fine in my xampp local-host but how can i deploy this to the internet through web-hosting i have the hosting and domain ready i have search online but all the similar project i am seeing uses local-host none of them are saying anything about how to deploy it to an online service.
Here are the PHP code in case their is something i need to change in it Here is the Configuration File

```
$db_user = 'root';
$db_passwoord = '';
$db_name = 'phprest';

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname='.$db_name.';charset=utf8',$db_user,$db_passwoord);

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

define('APP_NAME', 'PHP REST API TUTORIAL');
```

Initialization File

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', DS .'xampp' .DS. 'htdocs'.DS.'phprest');

defined('INC_PATH') ? null : define('INC_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS. 'includes');
defined('CORE_PATH') ? null : define('CORE_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS. 'core');

require_once(INC_PATH.DS."config.php");

require_once(CORE_PATH.DS."post.php");
```

My Post File

```
private $conn;
private $table = 'posts';

public $id;
public $category_id;
public $category_name;
public $title;
public $body;
public $author;
public $created_at;

public function __construct($db){
    $this->conn = $db;
}

public function read(){
    $query = 'SELECT
        c.name as category_name,
        p.id,
        p.category_id,
        p.title,
        p.body,
        p.author,
        p.created_at
        FROM
        ' .$this->table . ' p
        LEFT JOIN
            categories c ON p.category_id = c.id
            ORDER BY p.created_at DESC';

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}
```

My Read Data File

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include_once('../core/initialize.php');

$post = new Post($db);

$result = $post->read();

$num = $result->rowCount();

if($num > 0){
    $post_arr = array();
    $post_arr['data'] = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       extract($row);
       $post_item = array(
           'id' => $id,
           'title' =>$title,
           'body' => html_entity_decode($body),
           'author' => $author,
           'category_id' => $category_id,
           'category_name' => $category_name,
        );
        array_push($post_arr['data'], $post_item); 
    }

    echo json_encode($post_arr);
} else{
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'No posts found.'));
}
```

Here is a link to the database file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HgIYk0zIm9ZltMdAxJlDaGceWk-Po9J9

Answer (score 0):

Your web host should have provided you with the login credentials to FTP into the server, as well as the credentials for MySQL.

FTP into the server and put your files in it, but before you might want to change the values for the user / password / db name, as well as the host of MySQL so it corresponds to your server:

```php
$db_user = 'root'; // Change this
$db_passwoord = ''; // Change this
$db_name = 'phprest'; // Change this

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname='.$db_name.';charset=utf8',$db_user,$db_passwoord); // Change the host
```

Comment: Thanks alot but what will i change this line to "mysql:host=127.0.0.1" since 127.0.0.1 is xampp default localhost ip

Comment: It is for your localhost environment, but your hosting provider might have something else. It's not uncommon for providers to have web servers and database servers isolated from one another. Look into your hosting provider's control panel, you'll see your database host. It could be `localhost`, but it might be another IP or another host (e.g `mysql.example.com`). Whatever the case, make sure it corresponds to your host's settings.

Comment: Thank a lot i have done all you suggested but the webpage now give me a white page just empty do i have to call it in some other file like index.php or something

Comment: A white page is usually PHP's White Screen of Doom. It could mean that something is wrong in your code. Best way to start is to create an `index.php` file containing nothing but a simple `echo phpversion();` command. If you get a result, then your server works but something is wrong with your code. Start debugging from there.